# Plot lines get under the X-axis in Core Plot

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I've changed the look of my plots, and now the line of the plots accidentally goes under the X-axis. The problem looks like this (notice the black lines under the axis):

[image]

How can I get rid of it? I've change the plot line like this:

```
aaplPlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plots do not draw outside the plot area. You can control its size by setting padding on the plot area frame to push the edges of the plot area inwards. You will also need to adjust the plot ranges of the plot space to keep the same appearance.

Comment: This sounds reasonable enough but could you please provide some code or the place where I should look at.

Comment: Look at the "Curved Scatter Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* example app.